# Miniconda installation issue

Tags: installation, anaconda, conda, miniconda

I have been trying to install Miniconda on a server I am working on.
I tried to install the problem using various distributions, and for all of them, I got the following error:

PREFIX=**???(Hiding it intentionally)**/miniconda
Unpacking payload ...
Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh: line 404: ???(Hiding it intentionally)/conda.exe: cannot execute binary file
Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh: line 406: ???(Hiding it intentionally)/conda.exe: cannot execute binary file

My OS is: Fedora Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server ver 7.6

Would it be possible to know how the error can be fixed?

Comment: Isn’t Fedora 7 from the ‘00s? Which would mean it’s likely 32-bit architecture. Check with `uname -m`. Try installing a 32-bit build of miniconda (not x86_64).

Comment: @merv Thanks a lot for the answer. I figured out that the server's architecture is not x86_64, but it uses ppc64le architecture (which I never worked with before...). Seems like there is no easy way to install stuffs in this weird architecture...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Incompatible binary errors can be indicative of different architecture, which means different instruction sets. Architectures can be checked on Unix systems with `uname -m`.

OP identified the server is **ppc64le** architecture, so need to install an appropriate Miniconda version ([latest Miniconda3](https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-ppc64le.sh)) or possibly consider [Miniforge](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#miniforge) or one of its variants (Mambaforge is my preference), which also builds for many architectures.